# After I copy an image using WIN+Shft+S, is there a simple way to Save As .JPG?

Tags: windows, clipboard

I recently learned the Win+Shft+S keyboard shortcut and was hoping to replace the Snipping Tool with that. But what's a simple way to save as jpg something on the clipboard without a separate clipboard viewer tool?

Answer (score 1):

For semi-frequent use, I recommend to pin Paint to the taskbar (or say 'Open Paint', if 'Hey Cortana' is enabled). With Paint open, resize the blank canvas to about 2x2cm (or smaller, if you snip icons, etc.) and close Paint. Paint will remember this as the default canvas size.

From then on, when you want to save an image on the clipboard, launch Paint from the shortcut on the taskbar and select Paste. Paint will automatically resize the small blank canvas to hold the larger image so you can save it (to any supported format).

Once you close Paint, it is ready for next use. Or you can open additional Paint windows before closing the others without issue.